# Remove unnecessary files from release directory

Tags: c#, visual-studio, deployment, visual-studio-2015

I use NSIS to create an installer for my project. Wishing to have as small a filesize as I can, I began looking into my project's dlls, included files and prerequesites and noticed the following are all different:

- the minimal files required to run, as determined by educated guess + trial and error. I made sure the application works properly with this minmal set of files.
- the files exported by the "Publish" fonction for click once deployment (excluding click once specific files)
- the files in the release directory (excluding the pdb and vshost files)

It seems VS2015 generates an xml file for every dll. Some dlls I don't use and don't reference are copied as well.
My question is why is there so many unnecessary files and how can I configure VS2015 to not have them in /release?

Comment: Re: XML files, you can choose to build or not build XML documentation files in the Project Properties under "Build" (near the bottom of the page) (at least in VS2010).

Comment: Be careful about "minimal files required to run," as it may not be the same from machine to machine due to what you have already installed, etc.

Comment: @adv12 In both debug and release configurations, the "XML documentation" checkbox is not checked. It doesn't generate XML for my libraries, but it does for dlls like "EntityFramework".

Answer (score 0):

If you set VS build log level to verbose you will see exactly what happends during build and why a file goes to release folder. Once you determine the reason, you may either change your project file to adjust predefined behavior or add post-build event to remove unwanted files produced by build process.

MSBuild file, located at "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.targets" is very useful to dig into build process details as well.

However, if you indend to distribute the content of release folder to other machines I'd suggest you look at some installation software, like [Wix](http://wixtoolset.org/), for example. Once you create a setup project which includes files you do want, there will be no need to fight for release folder content.

Comment: I'm using VS2017 and in my case I'm deploying a website and it's copying solution files (.sln) and other -to me- unnecesary files. Why?